# How to set a css for an image where last three characters of src are a certian file type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to set a css for certain image file types?

Something like this here

```
$("#divID .className img").attr("src").slice(-3)==="jpg".css({
      width: 50%;
      // ..........
});
```

Its important to set it directly and not via if statement.

Comment: Would it be useful with a CSS only solution? https://jsfiddle.net/ao4opvez/1/ ... If, let me know and I can post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attribute selector?

```
$("#divID .className img[src$='.jpg']").css({
          width: 50%;
          // ..........
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using css like this

```
img[src*=".png"] {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

split it at the `.` and compare the extension and set the css if it matches:

```
$("#divID .className img").each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src").split(".");
  if(src[1] === 'jpg'){$(this).css('width','50%;')};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `filter()`

```
$("#divID .className img").filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr("src").slice(-3)==="jpg";    
}).css({
      width: '50%'
      // ..........
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do with [`filter()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjYnPCfxZzUAhWBPI8KHQZBDFsQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffilter%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIjOndwopfFySn6E1gc8znkMPSPw&sig2=Ho6OjC8hZKQrzlN1V6odkQ) `split('.')` the string with `.` and get the last one via [`pop()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgg8bgxZzUAhVBo48KHRVwCvcQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fpop&usg=AFQjCNFratEvkk3qWfG_RcpNl2-ixEY_fg&sig2=sj6S1gSlX41c-D4v05pmhw) .`toLowerCase()` used for match `.JPG` also .And you are missing the `''` in the dom of css

```
 $("img").filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr("src").toLowerCase().split('.').pop() == "jpg";
    }).css({
      'width':'10px'
 //...
    })
```

**Working example**

```js
$("img").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src").toLowerCase().split('.').pop() == "jpg";
}).css({'width':'50%'})
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="one.jpg">
<img src="one.jpg">
<img src="one">
```

Comment: need a `return` in `filter()`